# How to create MySQL workbench forms and reports

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, libreoffice

can you create forms and reports using MySQL workbench itself or you need php or other languages to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MySQL Workbench does not allow to create HTML forms or reports. It is a client tool to work with MySQL servers (manage, query) and to design databases (EER).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have created MYSQL DB using MYSQL Workbench. I want to connect it to Libreoffice. But Libreoffice doesn't show any direct connection option. Do you have any idea how can i achieve this. Basically i want to create a DB using MYSQL and connect it to Libreoffice for forms and reports

Comment: You need an [ODBC connector for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). LibreOffice will then use this connector for MySQL connections.